# create upload from file button in tab menu "Landed Cost" of Acumatica Purchase Receipt Screen

Tags: c#, acumatica

I need to create additional button "Upload From File" in tab menu Landed Cost of Purchase Receipt's screen. Please see the following screenshot.

[image]

I already create additional button in Document Details tab menu and it works, please refer to the following screenshot.

[image]

I create Extension Graph to provide this additional button.

```
public class POReceiptEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<POReceiptEntry>
{
#region Event Handlers
[PXViewName(Messages.POReceiptLine)]
    [PXImport(typeof(POReceipt))]
    [PXCopyPasteHiddenFields(typeof(POReceiptLine.allowComplete))]
    public PXSelect<POReceiptLine, Where<POReceiptLine.receiptType, Equal<Current<POReceipt.receiptType>>,
                    And<POReceiptLine.receiptNbr, Equal<Current<POReceipt.receiptNbr>>>>,
                    OrderBy<Asc<POReceiptLine.receiptType, Asc<POReceiptLine.receiptNbr, Asc<POReceiptLine.lineNbr>>>>> Transactions;
#endregion
```

}

I think this can be done with implement this additional button in Tab Menu Landed Cost, but I got an error message when I try to upload from excel file. Please refer to the following screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done following changes to import the data in landed cost tab grid

```
[PXViewName(Messages.POReceiptLine)]
[PXImport(typeof(POReceipt))]
    [PXCopyPasteHiddenFields(typeof(LandedCostTran.aPDocType), typeof(LandedCostTran.aPRefNbr), typeof(LandedCostTran.aPCuryInfoID), typeof(LandedCostTran.iNDocType), typeof(LandedCostTran.iNRefNbr))]
public PXSelect<LandedCostTran, Where<LandedCostTran.pOReceiptNbr, Equal<Current<POReceipt.receiptNbr>>,
  And<LandedCostTran.source, Equal<LandedCostTranSource.fromPO>>>> landedCostTrans;
```

I have enabled Upload file under Actionbar ==> Action and Mode ==> Allowupload

[image]

[image]

It Allows to upload the file and brings the upload mapping window to upload data

[image]

[image]